# How to send/store a simple string from a service worker when a notification is received?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I have a website that receives notifications from Firebase and I would like to redirect the user to a specific page (ex: home/news) but the websites requires the user to be logged in so when I try to access home/news it will check for a valid token if there is not one available it will redirect user to login page. After the login, the user will be redirected to home instead of home/news. So what I need is a way to store data from a service worker(even if the website is not opened) and read it when the user opens the site

Comment: Assuming your authentication happens on a server (and would there for require an internet connection), how would a server worker help in this situation? Wouldn't it be simpler to provide the login page with a "once logged in redirect to ..." value of some sort?

Comment: It would but how can I set that "once logged in redirect to ..." variable?

Comment: One common way is to add a query string to the login URL, e.g. `mysite.com/login?redirect=news` then send that with the login request, and have the server doing the authentication return a redirect header if it's successful.